# Using an order by with a not in

Tags: mongodb

Why am I not able to make this query works?

```
db.mydb.find(
    {"LETTER": {
        "$nin": ["a", "b", "c"]
    }
}, {
    "LETTER": 1,
    "LANGUAGE": 1
}).sort( { "LETTER": 1 } );
```

The error given is :

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33554457 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes",
    "code" : 17144
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating an index on the `LETTER` field by `db.mydb.ensureIndex({LETTER: 1})` and try the query again?

Comment: @chridam it returns me a date, I really don't know where is it from.. But I'm gonna take a look at the index

Comment: this may help you : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#use-indexes-to-sort-query-results

Comment: Yes my bad, the query is returning a good result with index, I just have to filter it :)